# I deposited the funds?

Tags: grammaticality

Should I say: 
I was deposited yesterday the funds 
OR: 
I deposited yesterday the funds.

- Can I add the 'was' or I'm not allowed to? 
  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. *BE* plus past participle is the passive construction, in which the semantic object becomes the syntactic subject:

> ACTIVE:    I deposited the funds yesterday.
>   PASSIVE: The funds **were** deposited yesterday.